# Flutter - Streambuilder with dropdown is not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, stream-builder

I have 3 nested streambuilder, everything is working fine except 3rd streambuilder, I am getting correct data on console while printing, But I am not getting correct data on Text widget and I am getting 'Loading' text, only else part is getting executed all the time. Below are my code and Attached is screenshot on result I am getting on my phone.

I am not sure what I did wrong.

[image]

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget _buildAskOf() {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil().setWidth(20)),
    child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AllColors().whiteColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
        child: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
            stream: _provider.askCreatorStream,
            builder: (context, snapshotAskOf) {
              if (snapshotAskOf.hasData) {
                return StreamBuilder<String>(
                    stream: _provider.askOfStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshotSelectedAsk) {
                      return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: ScreenUtil().setWidth(10),
                          ),
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            hint: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(30),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "Ask of",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  //color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(50),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            value: snapshotSelectedAsk.data,
                            items: snapshotAskOf.data.map((snapshotAskId) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: snapshotAskId,
                                child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                                    stream: _provider.getData(
                                        uid: snapshotAskId),
                                    builder: (context, snapshotUser) {
                                      UserModel userModel;
                                      if (snapshotUser.hasData) {
                                        userModel =
                                            UserModel.fromSnapshot(
                                                snapshotUser.data);
                                        print(
                                            'snapshotUser on dropdown: ${userModel.firstName} ${userModel.lastName}');

                                        return Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(30),
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                            snapshotUser.hasData?'${userModel.firstName} ${userModel.lastName}':'a',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: AllColors()
                                                  .primaryTextColor,
                                              fontSize:
                                              ScreenUtil().setSp(45),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }
                                      return Text('Loading');
                                    }),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              print('val askof: $val');
                              _provider.askOfSink(val);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
              return Text('No List');
            })),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lots of time I am able to solve this issue by just changing the Streambuilder to Futurebutider.

I am not sure why Streambuilder is not working. Please let me know if you find why this is not working or any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
final selectedItem = list.firstWhere((element) => element.id == _item!.id)
```